If then statement showing false instead of true
I am trying to format my spreadsheet so that is shows any dates greater than today as true.
My formula is =IF(F2>TODAY,”TRUE”) when inputting this it shows the dates that are greater than today as false, I’m not sure where I am going wrong.
The cells I am formulating against are also formulated to count plus a year or 2 years from another date in column I so I’m not sure if this is effecting it for example =I2+365 which gives me the date a year ahead.
I want to formulate all of the dates in column F that are greater than today from the formula in column I to show as true
=IF(F2>”TODAY”,”TRUE”)

You should use the Today function with paranthesis as;
=IF(F2>TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE)

Or =F2>TODAY()?
